# Calling Wix CustomAction

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msitransform

I am new to WIX and installation classes.

I am using WIX for getting user inputs from InstallWizards
i want to add a custom action.

I created one custom action, and created a set up project , I am not knowing how to use and call this custom action using wix classes or how do I call.

This [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jschaffe/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters/) says about creating customactions,but how do I use at runtime for any MSI?

Comment: That article you linked to explains how to build a CA and has examples of WiX source that you add to your project. Your question probably needs to be more specific or we can only point you at more tutorials https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/standard-libraries/custom-actions-and-user-interface/    or     https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/events-and-actions/extra-actions/

Comment: Hi, I would suggest posting your code, and explain exactly what you're trying to do. See [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Inside class creating msi session      private Session fSession;      Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Full, ref parent);                      fSession = Installer.OpenPackage(msiFile, true);                                                                                   fSession.DoAction("LaunchConditions");
 fSession.DoAction("License_Dialog");
 fSession.DoAction("Welcome_Dialog");                    fSession.DoAction(dailog);..how do i call Custom action from this session

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352117/msi-user-interface-wizard-session-with-wix                                                                             my actual requirement is to open Wizard and get all inputs from Userinterface wizard and update msi db or create transform

Comment: How to call CA from my C# code..or using wix session

Comment: You are trying to drive the install with DoAction calls from some code. MsiSetInternalUI is designed to be called from an outside program that is running the MSI file. If you look at its options you'll see that they correspond to msiexec command line options. The only way I could start to do what you are trying to do (capture properties from the install) is enumerate all the properties in the session database to find the ones you want (in a custom action) at the end of the UI sequence in a normal install.

Comment: PhilDW,Thanks for the response but then , i still did not get what you sugeested me,Another way  Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Full, ref parent); fSession = Installer.OpenPackage(msiFile, false);fSession.DoActionSequence("InstallUISequence");I got user interface wizard and i also can access User input,but i dont want to install,how can escape the installation

Comment: PhilDW  enumerating properties does not give the user inputs   only way that i got is to read like session of companyname but this is like a hard coding by taking  though i  get all properties from Microsoft documentation is there a way that we can directly read the updated MSI